# Upload image with RoR and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I recently deployed my ruby on rails app on Heroku and I am using the pg gem for my database.

I created a page where I can upload images and have them show on the main page and they are saved in a public folder within the app.

When I deployed it was working fine, but after sometime the images disappeared. When I looked at my Heroku logs I got the following:

```
  ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET]       "/assets/products/6/photos/medium/shanab.jpg"):
```

I think the images are saved, but I don't know how to check if they are still there.

Comment: Heroku only stores file on server temporarily, That is because each running dyno is an independent container (much like docker) which shared nothing with other dynos, and is destroyed when the app is restarted/deployed.

So any file written on disk will be lost when the dyno is restarted, and is not recoverable.

You need to configure paperclip or carrier-wave  to upload images to a dedicated file storage system like Amazon S3.

Comment: plz refer this link : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

Answer (score 0):

> but after sometime the images disappeared

Heroku runs an [`ephemeral file system`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) which means that each time you deploy a new version of your code, the old files/code are overwritten:

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, **with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code**. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted.

This means that even if your images are working for a time, each new deploy will basically overwrite them. This is probably the cause of the problem, although I can't be sure without further inspection.

--

The way around this is to use a [CDN](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CDN.html), most common (although incorrect) is to tie your app with `S3`.

I don't know which asset-processing gem you're using, but if it's [`Paperclip`](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip), you'll want to use the [inbuilt S3 functionality](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) to put all your image assets onto Amazon's servers:

```
#app/models/x.rb
class x < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :download,
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => Proc.new{|a| a.instance.s3_credentials }

  def s3_credentials
    {:bucket => "xxx", :access_key_id => "xxx", :secret_access_key => "xxx"}
  end
end
```